# postfix additional header addition

Tags: postfix, centos5, smtp-headers

```
X-LBSMTP-Spam-Policy: SendBlaster SMTP is a paid relay service.We do not tolerate UCE of any kind. Please report it ASAP to abuse@lbsmtp.org.
```

I want to add such a header to mails sent by my postfix mail server. I have postfix 2.33 in my centos5 server.
Is there a way to add this in postfix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this using

```
 smtp_header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/add_x_header
```

Create the file /etc/postfix/add_x_header with the following contents:

```
/^Subject: .*/ PREPEND X-LBSMTP-Spam-Policy: SendBlaster SMTP is a paid relay service.We do not tolerate UCE of any kind. Please report it ASAP to abuse@lbsmtp.org.
```

This will insert the header before the Subject line.

(Also, it's very nice to see you wanting to work to end spam from your domain - good luck!)

Comment: This is not working in my postfix actually i have postfix version 2.33 and this as i have seen works on version 2.5 or later.

Comment: Then I have no solution. Sorry!

Comment: thanks jenny D it is working now i switched to postfix 2.9.3 and bingo it works.

Comment: Glad it's working!